Best practices for sharing IntelliJ run configuration with secrets as env vars?
I'm working on a repo in IntelliJ and running the project requires that certain env vars are available and I'm wondering what would be the best way to make sure teammates can run the project without needing to request the env vars from someone else (i.e. make it self service/something they can follow in the readme). I know that you can save IntelliJ run configurations as files and check them into the repo, but then we'd be exposing secrets. Also, ideally I would like a way that's editor agnostic, i.e. if someone just wanted to run a gradle command in CLI they should be able to have the env vars available to them too.
Is there any plugin/tool that would allow us to load secrets from some other source that handles auth (e.g. AWS secret manager or some other vault) and inject them into the env vars/run configuration such someone could run the project either through IntelliJ or CLI without ever needing to save the secrets in a file (or need to ask for them to be sent over a message etc.)
